# Test original sha256 implementation using jest in React Native

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, jestjs

I have the following code:

```
import { sha256 } from 'react-native-sha256'
....
....

function doSomething(someString) {
  // ....
  const hash = await sha256(someString);
  // ...do something with the hash
}
```

For the tests that I want to write, I want to test using the original implementation of `sha256` that the function behaves the same for lowerCase and upperCase parameter. However, when running following test:

```
import { sha256 } from 'react-native-sha256';

jest.mock('react-native-sha256', () => {
   return {
       ...jest.requireActual('react-native-sha256')
   }
});

describe('Tests for sha256', () => {
    it('Lower case and upper case strings throw the same hash', async () => {
        const a = await sha256('parameter');
        const b = await sha256('PaRaMeTeR');
        expect(a).toEqual(b);
    })
});
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'sha256' of undefined

    at sha256 (/Users/home/app/node_modules/react-native-sha256/sha256.js:12:20)
```

and the particular file has the following:

```
/**
 * react-native-sha256
 * @flow
 */

'use strict';

const {NativeModules} = require('react-native')
const sha256Lib = NativeModules.sha256Lib;

export function sha256(data: string) {
  return sha256Lib.sha256(data);
}

export function sha1(data: string) {
  return sha256Lib.sha1(data);
}
```

How can I test this function?

Comment: I expect line 12 is `return sha256Lib.sha256(data);`? Not that SHA256 is not normally case-insensitive.

Comment: the wrapper comes from the `node_modules`, the path of that file is: `app/node_modules/react-native-sha256/sha256.js`

Comment: SHA256 will treat `parameter` and `PaRaMeTeR` differently. Your test will fail.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the mock? What is the purpose of the mock?